# Gae ndb structuredproperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have something like this:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    date=ndb.DateProperty()
    title=ndb.StringProperty()  
    content=ndb.TextProperty()

class User(ndb.Model):
    username=ndb.StringProperty()
    name=ndb.StringProperty()
    city=ndb.StringProperty() 
    books=ndb.StructuredProperty(Book, repeated=True)
```

The idea is to have several users and each user have several different books.

Once I have the user object:

```
user=User.query(User.username=="pepo").get()
```

I can get the list of books of that user easily:

```
user.books
```

but, how can I get, for example, the list of books ordered by date of that user? Or in general any query of the structuredproperty but related with a the user I alrealdy have.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have the user object, you can treat the `books` property as a normal list. To sort you can do:

```
sorted_books = sorted(user.books, lambda x: x.date)
```

You would do the sorting in-memory, not via a query (although I believe you can sort the result of a query on `User` by a structured property, it won't have any effect on the ordering of the property itself, just the order in which the `User` objects are returned).

For more information on how to sort lists in Python, view [this article](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html).